# NSDictionary after particular object is null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, null, nsdictionary

I made a NSDictionary, say

```
 NSDictionary *question = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  variable_first,@"first",
                                  variable_second,@"second",
                                  variable_third,@"third",
                                  variable_fourth,@"fourth",
                                  variable_fifth,@"fifth",
                                      nil];
```

Here, if Any one of

variable_first
variable_second
variable_third
variable_fourth
variable_fifth

Than, Dictionary will not save any key onwards.

lets say, if variable_third is null from server, than variable_fourth & variable_fifth will not be added, no matter they have values.

Can I see anywhere apple wrote this, or any idea why Objective-C is showing such behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: Given that the list is `nil`-terminated, one can easily extrapolate that `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` saves pairs of data until encountering `nil`

Comment: variable_first?variable_first:[NSNull null] ,@"first" use this way

Comment: while creating dictionary 1st check all 5 variables values, if they are null ,set blank to them & then assign to dictionary.

Comment: I know how to solve issue. I want to know reason and where APPLE has written it. Any documentation for Dictionary. @ALL

Comment: You should use the word "nil", because a nil pointer is hugely different from [NSNull null], which is usually called "null".

Comment: @Muhammad: Easier: variable_first ?: [NSNull null]

Comment: @gnasher729 Great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how NSDictionary works, read the documentation. It stops with the first nil object. That first nil value should usually be the nil that you add at the end, but if any other value is nil, that's where dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys stops.

You can use the modern syntax @{ key: value, key: value, ... }

In that case, if any of the values is nil, your app will crash. Which is 100 times better than silently misbehaving, because the app crashes, you find the reason, you fix it.

The fix: You mustn't try to add nil objects to a dictionary. There are two ways, and you need to decide which one you want: Either you start with a mutable dictionary, and add only those key/value pairs where the value is not nil. Or you add a value [NSNull null] instead of nil to the dictionary. Obviously when you access the dictionary, in one case these values will return nil, in the other case they will return [NSNull null]. Whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Its not allowed to insert `nil` value into `NSArray, NSMutableArray` or any such data structure. It will throw exception nil value inserted. you can instead insert `[NSNull null]` object in it. Use following snippet to check `nil` if yes then insert `Null` object else its value.

function to check null value before inserting into data structure.

```
static id isNil(id object)
{
    return object ?: [NSNull null];
}

NSDictionary *question = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              isNull(variable_first),@"first",
                              isNull(variable_second),@"second",
                              isNull(variable_third),@"third",
                              isNull(variable_fourth),@"fourth",
                              isNull(variable_fifth),@"fifth",
                                  nil];
```

It will insert `[NSNull null]` object where any of the value is `nil` and continue execution.

Comment: NSDictionary doesn't through any exception. So, its wrong; However NSArray throws exception and crashes.

Comment: isNull is an awful method name, because it doesn't return whether the argument is null, but something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the getter of all these variables like this

```
-(NSString*) variable_first {
  if(!_variable_first){
    _variable_first = @"";
   }
  return _variable_first;
}
```

In this way even if variable_first is null from server, you will be adding it as an empty string in your dictionary and the problem which you are facing will not occur.

Comment: No Usama, Its not a good idea to over-ride each and every object. I have generic method. I know how to handle them. I better know how to insert value. I want to know why this issue occurs. Dipen has given a closed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:-

```
   NSDictionary *question = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              a?a:[NSNull null],@"first",
                              b?b:[NSNull null],@"second",
                              c?c:[NSNull null],@"third",
                              d?d:[NSNull null],@"fourth",
                              ef?ef:[NSNull null],@"fifth",
                              nil];
```